# Hive: Extract Data From Nested JSON and Append

Tags: sql, json, hive, hql, cross-join

I have a hive table with IDs and JSON such as below:

```
id   json
----------
21 | {"temp":"3","list":[{"url":"aaa.com"},{"url":"bbb.com"}]}
42 | {"temp":"2","list":[{"url":"qqq.com"},{"url":"vvv.com"}]}
```

The desired output is such as below:

```
id   url
----------
21 | aaa.com
21 | bbb.com
42 | qqq.com
42 | vvv.com
```

Would anyone help with this hive query?

Applying explode() directly does not work as json column is a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below query:

```
hive> with cte as (
select stack(2,int(21),string('{"temp":"3","list":[{"url":"aaa.com"},{"url":"bbb.com"}]}'),
int(42),string('{"temp":"2","list":[{"url":"qqq.com"},{"url":"vvv.com"}]}')) as (id,json))  
select id,url from (
select id,
split(
regexp_replace(
        get_json_object(json,'$.list.url'),
  '(\\[|\\]|\")','')
 ,',')jsn from cte)t 
lateral view explode(jsn)asd as url;
```

**Output:**

```
id      url
21      aaa.com
21      bbb.com
42      qqq.com
42      vvv.com
```

**Functions Explanation:**

**`Stack`** --is used to create sample data

**`get_json_object`** -- to extract data from json string

**`regexp_replace`** --to replace `[,],"` characters

**`split`** --split on `,` and this will return array

**`explode`** --use array column to explode

Comment: Thank you this is great!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_json_object()` and `explode()` methods together as

```
select id,
       get_json_object(jst.js,'$.temp.url') as url
  from ( select explode(json) as js FROM json_tab ) jst
```

Comment: I realized that the json column is a string. I got an error `explode() takes an array or a map as a parameter`.